# NoSuchElementException reading/ scanning input

Tags: java

Here is the main problem:

```
    java.util.NoSuchElementException: No line found
        at java.util.Scanner.nextLine(Unknown Source)
        at ExamAnalysis.main(ExamAnalysis.java:21)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at edu.rice.cs.drjava.model.compiler.JavacCompiler.runCommand(JavacCompiler.java:271)
```

The program compiles and runs. It's just that I am either getting the java.util.NoSuchElementException along with my five jother errors with (answer.charAt(i) == char) near the bottom. Here is my program:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

class ExamAnalysis
 {
   public static void main(String [] args) throws FileNotFoundException
   {
       Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);  
       System.out.println("Please type the correct answers to the exam questions, one right after the other: ");
       String answers = keyboard.nextLine();
       System.out.println("Where is the file with all the student responses? ");
       String responses = keyboard.nextLine();
       Scanner read = new Scanner(new File(responses));


        while (read.hasNextLine())
        {
         for (int i = 0; i <= 10; i++)
         {
          responses = read.nextLine();
          int p = 1;
          p += i;
          System.out.println("Student " + p + " responses: " + responses.substring(0,10));
           }
            System.out.println("Thank you for the data on 9 students. Here's the analysis: ");
            resultsByStudents(responses, answers);
            analysis(responses);
           }
        }

         public static void resultsByStudents(String responses, String answers)
          { 
           System.out.println ("Student #        Correct        Incorrect       Blank");
           System.out.println ("~~~~~~~~~        ~~~~~~~        ~~~~~~~~~       ~~~~~");
           int student = 0;
           int correct = 0;
           int incorrect = 0;
            int blank = 0;

         for (int i = 0; i <= 9; i++) 
         {
          for (int j = 0; j <= responses.length(); j++)
          {
           if ((responses.charAt(j)) == answers.charAt(j))
            correct++; 
           else if ((responses.charAt(j)) != answers.charAt(j))
            incorrect++;
           else 
            blank++;   
            }
             System.out.println(student + "        " + correct + "        " + incorrect + "        " + blank);
             student++;
        }    
      }

     public static void analysis(String responses)
     {
      System.out.println("QUESTION ANALYSIS   (* marks the correct response)");
      System.out.println("~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~");


     //stores the percentage of each choice chosen  
    double A = 0;
    double B = 0;
    double C = 0;
    double D = 0;
    double E = 0;
    double X = 0;
    // tallys every variable chosen per question

    for (int i = 0; i <= 10; i++) // go through all the questions
    {
     for (int j = 0; j <= responses.charAt(i); j++) //go through all the student responses
     {
      // variable that are being tallied
      int chooseA = 0;
      int chooseB = 0;
      int chooseC = 0;
      int chooseD = 0;
      int chooseE = 0;
      int chooseBlank = 0;
     //variables take percentage of choices that have been chosen from each student
      A = chooseA/9;
      B = chooseB/9;
      C = chooseC/9;
      D = chooseD/9;
      E = chooseE/9;
      X = chooseBlank/9;
      // variables that will print the asterisk with certain character of correct answer
      String a = "A";
      String b = "B";
      String c = "C";
      String d = "D";
      String e = "E";
      String blank = "blank";


      if (responses.charAt(j) == A)
       chooseA++;
      else if (responses.charAt(j) == B)
       chooseB++;
      else if (responses.charAt(j) == C)
       chooseC++;
      else if (responses.charAt(j) == D)
       chooseD++;
      else if (responses.charAt(j) == E)
       chooseE++;
      else 
       chooseBlank++; 


     System.out.println("Question #" + i);
      if (answers.charAt(i) == 'A') a = "A*"; // answers cannot be resolved(I already made it a  global variable in my main method.)
      else if (answers.charAt(i) == 'B') b = "B*";// answers cannot be resolved
      else if (answers.charAt(i) == 'C') c = "C*";// answers cannot be resolved
      else if (answers.charAt(i) == 'D') d = "D*";// answers cannot be resolved
      else if (answers.charAt(i) == 'E') e = "E*";// answers cannot be resolved
      System.out.println(a + "        " + b + "        " + c + "        " + d + "        " + e + "        " + blank);
    System.out.println (chooseA + "        " + chooseB + "        " + chooseC + "        " + chooseD + "        " + chooseE + "        " + chooseBlank );
    System.out.println (A + "        " + B + "        " + C + "        " + D + "        " + E + "        " + X);
  }
}
```

}
}

Answer (score 2):

```
while (read.hasNextLine())         
{          
    for (int i = 0; i <= 10; i++)          
    {       
        responses = read.nextLine();
        int p = 1;           
        p += i;           
        System.out.println("Student " + p + " responses: " + responses.substring(0,10));            
    }             
    System.out.println("Thank you for the data on 9 students. Here's the analysis: ");             
    resultsByStudents(responses, answers);             
    analysis(responses);            
    }         
}
```

Your logic here is confusing you. read.nextLine(); "Advances this scanner past the current line and returns the input that was skipped. This method returns the rest of the current line, excluding any line separator at the end. The position is set to the beginning of the next line."

So you are saying, does it have a line? If so, read the next 10...well...11 lines, which isn't what you want. You don't know if there are 11 lines past this point. Don't know what that text file looks like, but you will want to restructure this part to either say, "While it has a next line", or "Read 11 lines"

Comment: isn't my scanner read supposed to read whatever is in my input file?

Comment: all I am doing for the first part is incrementing the student by 1 and assigning each student a response from my input file each student will take one line from my input file which has 10 different answers

Comment: I understand what I am doing. The program is going through the first part but it won't go to the others because of the java.util.NoSuchElementException

Comment: Well, then you problem may simply be the fact that you are reading 11 lines when you meant 10. change the for loop to 

for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)

If you know that for every student there will be 10 lines after, then the way the program is set up is fine, but you're getting a no such element exception because you're reading 11 lines, not 10.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the for loop may resolve the issue. You are checking only once by using `while(hasNextLine() )` but calling `read.nextLine()` 10 times in for loop.

```
for (int i = 0; i <= 10; i++)
         {
          responses = read.nextLine();
         .......
           }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int i = 0;
int numberOfStudents = 9;
while (i < numberOfStudents && read.hasNextLine()){
    responses = read.nextLine();
    i++;
    System.out.println("Student " + i + " responses: " + responses.substring(0,10));
}
System.out.println("Thank you for the data on "+ numberOfStudents +" students. Here's the        analysis: ");
resultsByStudents(responses, answers);
analysis(responses);
```

i < numberOfStudents : makes the required number of inserts

read.hasNextLine() : checks if there is input from console. If not the program waits for input.

```
for (int i = 0; i <= 10; i++)
```

count from 0 -> 10 = 11 students